# A continuum which is both Suslinean and non-Suslinean?

Tags: gn.general-topology, continuum-theory

*Continuum* means compact connected metrizable with more than one point.

A continuum is  *Suslinean* if every collection of pairwise disjoint subcontinua is countable.

There is an apparent contradiction in the literature I would like to resolve...

In Example 3 at the end of **Paper A**, there is constructed a continuum $Y:=X/\sim$ which is the quotient of another continuum $X$. It is clear from the construction that $X$ is Suslinean, and since the quotient map is monotone  $Y$ is also Suslinean. Actually, the author claims $X$ and $Y$ are hereditarily locally connected, and such continua are automatically known to be Suslinean.

On the other hand, $Y$  is the closure of a ray (a one-to-one continuous image of $[0,1)$) such that the ray is first category in $Y$.  In other words, the ray and its complement are each dense in $Y$.  It follows that there is a sequence of pairwise disjoint arcs in $Y$ which converges to $Y$ in the Hausdorff distance.  By Theorem 30 in **Paper B**, $Y$ is non-Suslinean.

**Question 1**: Am I correct in finding a contradiction?

**Question 2**: Is Example 3 correct? Specifically, why is it Hausdorff (and therefore metrizable)?  I found a couple of typos, e.g. $A_n$ should be $C_n\cup \bigcup ...$ and $\overline{z_1 z_1}$ should be $\overline{z_1 z_2}$, but otherwise it seems okay.

If there is a problem with Theorem 30, then I think the error must be in the proof of Lemma 29.  Specifically there is a claim that $H_W$ is non-degenerate since it is an inverse limit of non-degenerate continua. This is a false statement in general because we can take the continua $[0,1/n]$ with bonding maps the inclusions $[0,1/(n+1)] \hookrightarrow[0,1/n]$, and the inverse limit is just the single point $\langle 0,0,..\rangle$. However, since each factor of the inverse limit for $H_W$ projects into $\partial U$ and $\partial V$ in the first factor, the inverse limits on preimages of these boundary sets should be non-empty and disjoint subsets of $H_W$...

Upon closer inspection, the proof of Lemma 29 (Paper B) is flawed in more ways than one.  I'm not sure it can be saved.

At this point I would lean toward the example being correct.  I really just need to see that $Y=X/\sim$ is Hausdorff.

---

**Paper A**:

*Tymchatyn, E. D.*, [**Some rational continua**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1216/RMJ-1983-13-2-309), Rocky Mt. J. Math. 13, 309-319 (1983). [ZBL0514.54022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0514.54022).

**Paper B**:

*Mouron, Christopher*, [**The topology of continua that are approximated by disjoint subcontinua**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2008.08.010), Topology Appl. 156, No. 3, 558-576 (2009). [ZBL1165.54012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1165.54012).

Comment: Good question, bad title. I suggest something with Suslinean in the title, e.g. "To Be Suslinean Or Not; That Is The Question". Gerhard "Brush Up On Your Shakespeare" Paseman, 2019.04.12.

Comment: Should it be obvious that if $X$ is Suslinean then so is $X / \sim$?

Comment: @WillBrian Maybe not in general, but the quotient map  here is monotone so that should do it.

Comment: @D.S.Lipham: I presume you've checked that both papers are using the identical definition of "Suslinean"?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, the definitions are the same.

Comment: At this point, you might want to look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31337/how-do-i-fix-someones-published-error.

Comment: @WillBrian Thanks for the link, I will consider the advice in the answers. My situation is that I uploaded a paper to arXiv about a week ago with a result relying on Theorem 30. Then I discovered the example which called everything into question. I will likely contact the authors. My `result' may still be true and we can possibly even work on that together. In the meantime I probably need to update my arXiv paper with some explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Example 3 in Paper A is indeed a counterexample to Theorem 30 in Paper B.

Lemma 29 must also be false because it implies Theorem 30.

The only thing left to verify is that $Y=X/\sim$ (from Example 3) is Hausdorff, so that $Y$ is actually a *metrizable* continuum.  This can be proved in a few steps:

1. For every compact $K\subseteq [0,1]$ the set $$\widehat{K}:=K\cup \bigcup \big\{\overline{z_1 z_2}:z_1\text{ and }z_2\text{ are consecutive endpoints of some }C_n \text{ and }(z_1\in K\text{ or }z_2\in K)\big\}$$ is a closed (compact) subset of $X$.
2. If $U$ is any open subset of $X$ containing an element $y\in Y$, then   $$V=X\setminus\widehat{[0,1]\setminus U}$$ is an open subset of $X$ which is a union of members of $Y$, and $y\subseteq V\subseteq U$.
3. $Y$ is Hausdorff by  2 and normality of $X$.

We can argue  1 as follows.  Let $x$ be any point in the closure of $\hat K$.  Suppose for a contradiction that  $x\notin \hat K$. Then $x\in [0,1]\setminus K$ and there is a sequence of semi-circular arcs $\overline{z^n_1 z^n_2}\in Y$ with $z^n_1\in K$ and $z^n_2\to x$. (I assume without loss of generality that the subscripts on the $z$'s are arranged in this way).

Since $d(x,K)>0$ this means infinitely many semicircles have radius greater than some positive constant.  But this is impossible by the construction of $X$. Therefore $x\in \hat K$   and $\hat K$ is compact.

Now 1 $\Rightarrow$ 2 $\Rightarrow$ 3 and the proof is complete.